# swift programming - storyboard how to add more buttons on a viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, swift, storyboard, scrollview, simulator

Hi I'm new to iphone programming and I'm having problem with scrolling on the storyboard. Let's say I need to add 30 buttons on a viewcontroller inside a scrollview, but the screen size only fits 15, how do I scroll down and add more buttons.
[screen shot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xF4f.png)
Another problem I have is that when I run the iphone app on the simulator, it can only scroll down too the button 13 even though there are 15 buttons on my view controller.
[screen shot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5rfn.png)
Thanks for your help.

Comment: why can't you use the UITableView?

Comment: I use UITableView on one of my other viewcontroller, and it still only show partial data when I run it on the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can scroll the scrollView on the storyboard. Scroll down and then add buttons.
2. You need to set a size appropriate for Scroll ContentSize. Take a note at that.

Please do provide more info from. Its gonna make the resolution process easy.

Take a look at this link for solid ScrollView intro:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/76436/use-uiscrollview-scroll-zoom-content-swift

Comment: hi, that's all the info I have right now as I'm trying to get the layout right. I can't seem to scroll down on the scrollview. For the Scroll ContentSize, how much do I need to set? Eventually, I will have to populate the scrollview with a dynamic table, so I can't know the size in advanced. Why doesn't it auto scroll to fit all the data?

Answer (score 0):

In the storyboard... Just make the view bigger. In your case, you want to change the height:

[image: Image showing where the width and height adjustment are.]

For the problem of not being able to scroll across all your images. You need to make sure the scroll view is pinned to all four sides of the parent view and that the height and width are all set-up for the content inside the scroll view. (make sure there are no warnings associated with the scroll view in the storyboard.)

Comment: Hi thanks, I fixed the first problem by setting the size bigger using freeform. But can you give an example on the 2nd problem. I'm not sure how you pinned to all four sides of the parent view and that the height and width are setup inside the scroll view. Eventually, I want to dynamically pop from an array so the more data there is to the array, will the height grow dynamically?